# Error when trying to sort array using predicates

Tags: ios, xcode, arrays, ios6

I'm struggeling with an error occurring  when trying to populate an array with the filtered results of another array.

I've defined a global array named allArray in the .h-file, this array is containing about 100 objects. Then, I want the user to be able to search for a specific object, and I've tried to develop it using predicates:

```
  -(IBAction)searchChanged:(id)sender {
    //The searchfield's value has been changed.

    NSString *searchString = searchField.text;
    NSPredicate *searchPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self CONTAINS[c] %@", searchString];
    NSMutableArray *tempSearchArray = [allArray filterUsingPredicate:searchPredicate];
    [filteredArray removeAllObjects];
    [filteredArray addObjectsFromArray:tempSearchArray];
}
```

I end up getting an error when I create tempSearchArray.

> Initializing 'NSMutableArray *__strong' with an expression of
>   incompatible type 'void'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

filterUsingPredicate doesn't return an array, it returns nothing(void).

From the description:

"Evaluates a given predicate against the array’s content and leaves only objects that match"

You should instead use:

```
filteredArrayUsingPredicate
```

Comment: It really depends on what you are trying to achieve. I updated my post with what i expect your intentions to be!

Answer (score 0):

As the Docs will tell you, filterUsingPredicate has a void return value.
See here:

[NSMutableArray Class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

That means that you cannot assign that return value to another array.
You need to use this method on the original array, along the lines of

```
[allArray filterUsingPredicate:somePredicate];
```

arrArray will be stripped of any elements that dont match the predicate.

Now proceed with these results as you wish.

Have Fun

Answer (score 0):

filterUsingPredicate returns a void and not an array. You might want to consider using a filteredArrayUsingPredicate instead